# OnLocationChanged CallBacked Never Get Called While Using Google Map Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

Hello Guys This may be asked many many times but i couldn't find any solution from that so am making this post let me explain my problem i have simple google map application in that onlocationchanged callback never get called don't know where am making mistake let me post the code:

```
public  class VisitTravel extends  AppCompatActivity implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;

        LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        Location mCurrentLocation;
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visit_travel);
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();

    SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);


   /// tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

@Override
public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        }

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
        } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
        }
        }

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    Location mLastLocations = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    Log.d("insideready","ready");
    if (mLastLocations != null) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocations.getLatitude(), mLastLocations.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                latLng, 12);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);}
else {
        startLocationUpdates();

    }
}
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            Toast.makeText(this, "LocationNotUpdated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(VisitTravel.this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission
                            .ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    20);

        } else {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                createLocationRequest();
                Log.e("locupdate","connected");
                PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

                //       Toast.makeText(this, "LocationUpdatedStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
        }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
        mCurrentLocation = location;
     //   mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
     //   updateUI();
        }




protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
        mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
        }

@Override
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
      //  startLocationUpdates();
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
        }
        }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

In this on LocationChanged never getting called can anyone help me and for addition information am having background service which used to fetch location for every certain time in that i have separate instance of google api client is that affecting this one ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please move to startLocationUpdate method from if condition. Put it on the first line of onConnected Method.

Comment: am just checking whether lastknown location is available is there anything wrong in this ?

Comment: still not working

Comment: Please let me know which methods are called in sequence.

Comment: need to move the camera to current location and i want onlocationchange call back needs to get called for periodic time

Comment: in this onconnected method am trying to move camera to current location for that i check if lastknow location available if not il request for location from there onlocation change call back need to get trigger

Comment: Please change Interval and Fastest Interval to 0 and then check.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149568/discussion-between-chirag-raval-and-m-yogeshwaran).